Is there any way to install Ubuntu onto a Apple silicon mac?
I would like to install Ubuntu onto my Apple silicon mac mini. The chipset is the Apple M2 Pro, and it currently runs macOS Somona Ver. 14.6, and the model identifiers would be Mac14,12. Is this even possible?
Edit: I read an article (https://www.corellium.com/blog/linux-m1) saying it WAS, but it failed for me. prehaps i did something wrong? I will try again.

That article talks of porting Linux.  It doesn't say Ubuntu.  Linux is more generic than Ubuntu

This question is similar to: Is there a possible Ubuntu install on Apple Silicon hardware?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@muru I also reviewed this as a duplicate because its accepted answer is the most compatible with Apple silicon hardware.

While Ubuntu does not officially support apple silicon macs, the Fedora based Asahi Linux and the Ubuntu based Ubuntu Asahi project support these macs.
Asahi Linux is the parent project, and will have better support. You can find device support here.
To install, just run the single installation command available on their websites inside MacOS, and it will guide you to automatically partition the system drive, and configure a dual boot.

thank you random citizen!
